# Interpretation variants of binary operators

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, operator-precedence

I'm writing a grammar for a language that contains some binary operators that can also be used as unary operator (argument to the right side of the operator) and for a better error recovery I'd like them to be usable as nular operators as well).
My simplified grammar looks like this:
start:
    code EOF
;

```
code:
    (binaryExpression SEMICOLON?)*
;

binaryExpression:
    binaryExpression BINARY_OPERATOR binaryExpression //TODO: check before primaryExpression
    | primaryExpression
;

    primaryExpression:
            unaryExpression
            | nularExpression
    ;

    unaryExpression:
        operator primaryExpression
        | BINARY_OPERATOR primaryExpression
    ;

    nularExpression:
        operator
        | BINARY_OPERATOR
        | NUMBER    
        | STRING
    ;

        operator:
            ID
        ;
```

`BINARY_OPERATOR` is just a set of defined keywords that are fed into the parser.
My problem is that Antlr prefers to use `BINARY_OPERATOR`s as unary expressions (or nualr ones if there is no other choice) instead of trying to use them in a binary expression as I need it to be done.
For example consider the following intput: `for varDec from one to twelve do something` where `from`, `to` and `do` are binary operators the output of the parser is the following:
[image: ParseTree]
As you can see it interprets all binary operators as unary ones.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following: Try to match each `BINARY_OPERATOR` in a binary expression and **only if that is not possible** try to match them as a unary expression and if that isn't possible as well then it might be considered a  nular expression (which can only be the case if the `BINARY_OPERATOR`is the only content of an expression).

Has anyone an idea about how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I find your use of the word `operator` confusing, particularly `operator: ID`. I'd normally consider that an *operand*. And why do you allow `BINARY_OPERATOR` to be a "nullar expression"? That must be ambiguous.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the java tag, as this question has nothing to do with java.

Comment: The problem is that the language I'm building the grammar for does not really have any keywords or anything. the only thing the parser knows about are the `BINARY_OPERATOR`s but they still can be used in nular or unary expressions. What I'm trying to say is that this grammar is only to applying the language's syntactical rules to **any** given input. Therefore each `ID` can be an operator (which it actually really is in most of the cases)

Comment: Oh wait I just got your point @rici ... okay yes you're right I should call it an operand. And the problem persists even if I don't allow `BINARY_OPERATOR` as an operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly standard approach is to use a single recursive rule to establish the acceptable expression syntax. ANTLR is default left associative, so `op expr` meets the stated unary op requirement of "argument to the right side of the operator". See, pg 70 of TDAR for a further discussion of associativity.

Ex1: `-y+x`  -> `binaryOp{unaryOp{-, literal}, +, literal}`

Ex2: `-y+-x` -> `binaryOp{unaryOp{-, literal}, +, unaryOp{-, literal}}`

```
expr
    : LPAREN expr RPAREN
    | expr op expr         #binaryOp
  //| op expr              #unaryOp   // standard formulation
    | op literal           #unaryOp   // limited formulation
    | op                   #errorOp
    | literal
    ;

op  : .... ;

literal
    : KEYWORD
    | ID
    | NUMBER    
    | STRING
    ;
```

Comment: The problem still is the same. Because `BINARY_OPERATOR`s are allowed to be used in unary expressions this grammar always resolve the ambiguity in favour of the unary expression and keeps ignoring the binary expression alternative. The resulting parse tree is exactly the same as the one I included in my question...

Comment: If a limited definition of a unitary expression is desired, just directly specify what is acceptable. Here, to exclude binary expression from unitary, means that a unitary must be `op literal`, as shown in the updated answer. If there are other valid formulations of a unitary expression, add them as alternatives. Ultimately, the `expr` rule should present a tailored list of all valid formulations of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You allow operators to act like operands ("nularExpression") and operands to act like operators ("operator: ID"). Between those two curious decisions, your grammar is 100% ambiguous, and there is never any need for a binary operator to be parsed. I don't know much about Antlr, but it surprises me that it doesn't warn you that your grammar is completely ambiguous.

Antlr has mechanisms to [handle and recover from errors](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#catching-exceptions). You would be much better off using them than writing a deliberately ambiguous grammar which makes erroneous constructs part of the accepted grammar. (As I said, I'm not an Antlr expert, but there are Antlr experts who pass by here pretty regularly; if you ask a *specific* question about error recovery, I'm sure you'll get a good answer. You might also want to search this site for questions and answers about Antlr error recovery.)

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. But the problem still persists when I'm not allowing `BINARY_OPERATOR`s as a nular expression. And it is definately valid to use them as unary expressions...

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm going to write down now is what @GRosenberg meant with his answer. However as it took me a while to fully understand it I will provide a concrete solution for my problem in case someone else is stumbling across this question and is searching or an answer:

The trick was to remove the option to use a `BINARY_OPERATOR` inside the `unaryExpression` rule because this always got preferred. Instead what I really wanted was to specify that if there was no left side argument it should be okay to use a `BINARY_OPERATOR` in a unary way. And that's the way I had to specify it:

```
binaryExpression:
    binaryExpression BINARY_OPERATOR binaryExpression
    | BINARY_OPERATOR primaryExpression
    | primaryExpression
;
```

That way this syntax only becomes possible if there is nothing to the left side of a `BINARY_OPERATOR` and in every other case the binary syntax has to be used.